# How to get a list of elements with Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a list of web elements in Selenium. My issue now is that there are 4 gifs that can all be clicked on but all hold the same values. I need to make a list of them so I can choose which one I want. Here is my line of code

```
List<IWebElement> createGifs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[@ src='images/document_create.gif']"));
```

Everywhere I look online has this as a suitable answer. However I am receiving the error:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish what I am looking for or how to get around this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert that to `ReadOnlyCollection` and also make sure you have the `using System.Collections.Generic;` imports

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> createGifs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[@ src='images/document_create.gif']"));
```

If you do want to use `List` then use `ToList()`

```
List<IWebElement> createGifs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[@ src='images/document_create.gif']")).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

To Clarify the `ISearchContext.FindElements` method of Selenium returns `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` by default. See [this](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)

Comment: as a read only would this allow me to call on a member of it like createGifs[3].click(); ?

Comment: I am having trouble with this part as it says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ....IredOnlyCollection

Comment: My Bad the second option would. I misunderstood. You cannot use index with `ReadOnlyCollection` directly need to use Linq. Instead go the second option and use `createGifs[2].Click()` like that

Comment: @Saifur You should be able to use direct indexing with a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. In point of fact, I routinely do this with the result of `FindElements`. Do **not** confuse this with the newer `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface, which was just introduced in .NET 4.5. The WebDriver .NET language bindings do not use any features specific to .NET 4.5/4.6.

Comment: @JimEvans You are right. I meant to write `IReadOnlyCollection` in m y previous comment. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @user3352075 As JimEvans mentioned I was little confused about the `IReadOnlyCollection` interface and `ReadOnlyCollection`. If fact, you can use indexing with `ReadOnlyCollection` but not the `IReadOnlyCollection` interface. On the other hand, WebDriver's `FindElement` method returns the `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` not `IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `IReadOnlyCollection` to a List.

For Example, if you are searching for `li` then following should do.

```
//get readonly list
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> li_element_list =driver.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

//create new list
List<IWebElement> allHandles2 = new List<IWebElement>(li_element_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<IWebElement> createGifs = new List<IWebElement> (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[@ src='images/document_create.gif']")));
```

This worked for me just fine.